# Calling an angular component from another component

Tags: angular, routes, custom-element

[Error occurred when calling a component from another component in angular 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIBpl.png)

Comment: Share either your code or stackblitz, it would be a minor issue in module.

Comment: add your child component to app.module.ts also

Comment: your app-land-header component must be in the module where you has home.component (in Declarations) or in a module that was imported in the module you has home.component and declare in exports. See the docs: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules